# How to remove duplicate values as row index increases in python

Tags: python, csv

I am reading from a CSV file and have duplicate percent values in the Percent column but I would like to remove the rest of duplicated percent values except the first one as Test Name changes. I also don't want to remove rows.

Here is what I have right now:
[image]

And I would like to have this outcome:
[image]

Comment: can you show the code that you have tried? give a minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with np.nan and pandas Series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['Amazon',46,'blabla'],
                   [np.nan,46,'blabla'],
                   ['Google',37,'blabla'],
                   [np.nan,37,'blabla']],columns=['Name','Percent','blabla'])


val = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i in df.loc[df['Name'].notnull()].index.values.tolist():
        val.append(df['Percent'][i])
    else:
        val.append(np.nan)

df['Percent'] = pd.Series(val)
```